# Access 2010 - Bound Textbox - Only updating newest record created

Tags: ms-access, textbox, record

I am trying to update the textbox for the current request that I have opened. After making changes to the bound textbox (regardless of the record number current being edited) it modifies the tblVendorRequests.VendorDiscussionNotes for the newest request created within the table.

- My form is a Single Form
- My record source for my form is a table (tblVendorRequests)
- My textbox (txtVenConLog) is using tblVendorRequests.VendorDiscussionNotes as its control source

For instance, say I am trying to add notes "Hello World" to request number 242. Request 242's notes remain the same, but the "Hello World is added to the newest record instead (overwriting the existing text that was in the request).

I have done a good amount of searching on the topic, and have not found a satisfactory answer on why this would be.

Any ideas would highly appreciated!

Comment: Weird. Please add screenshots of design view + form view of your form. You can't add images yet, but you can upload them to imgur.com and add the links to your question.

Comment: Andre, I redesigned my form to split the functions into 2 separate forms and that seems to have resolved the issue. I believe the issue was that when I 'opened' a record, it was not behaving like it would if the record-opening function resulted in calling a form to open with specific criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned my form to split the functions into 2 separate forms and that seems to have resolved the issue. I believe the issue was that when I 'opened' a record, it was not behaving like it would if the record-opening function resulted in calling a form to open with specific criteria.